Hand symbol now showing on Dynamic button icon upon hover
I have a dynamic button in my IG.
Select null as link, empno, emp_name,dept from employees;
So link column has following attributes:
<title="" aria-label="" data-requestid="&EMP_NO!ATTR."  class="t-Button t-Button--icon increase-sal-btn"><span aria-hidden="true" class="t-Icon fa fa-times-circle-o u-color-3-text"></span>

Intially it was a button with icon but i want only icon to display.. Above code displays only icon but upon hover the hand icon should show indicating its a link but it doesn't happen.
Original code with button:
<button type="button" title="" aria-label="" data-requestid="&EMP_NO!ATTR."  class="t-Button t-Button--icon increase-sal-btn"><span aria-hidden="true" class="t-Icon fa fa-times-circle-o u-color-3-text"></span></button>

How can i correct the html and show its a link and its depicted?

There is no "hand icon" because that markup has no attributes that indicate it is a link. The best way is to always go back to the button builder to generate your button and then modify that markup (add modifier classes for color and the class(es) used for the dynamic action). You can create a button that looks like a link:

